# IONIC - Window CLI issue when I build app

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework, command-line-interface, build-error

IONIC - Window CLI issue when I build app, can't figure out where I have done mistake in installation or configuration as in my other computer it build successfully without any issue

Please suggest 
**

```
:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: D:\Sanny Stuffs\AppDev\myApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen\SplashScreen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources
:transformClassesWithDexForDebugjava.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main"
FAILED
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main"

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 52.011 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""D:\Sanny Stuffs\AppDev\myApp\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "D:\Sanny Stuffs\AppDev\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have version conflict.

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Update Java JDK to the latest version and Cordova as well.

Comment: My system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v4.4.7

java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)


What should be change to whick version as both looks latest version

Comment: maybe this link will help you: 

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/05/fixing-unsupported-majorminor-version.html